# FOL: Two friends have different friends

Tags: first-order-logic

I am new to FOL, and I have some difficulties understanding it. Here are two things:

1. Two PEOPLE have different friends
2. Two friends have the same other
   friend

A relation for "a is a friend of b" is given by E(a,b)

My solution would be

1. $\forall$ a,b $\rightarrow$  $\neg$(E(a,v) $\wedge$ E(b,v))
2. $\forall$ a,b E(a,b) $\rightarrow$ E(a,v) $\wedge$ E(b,v)

where a,b are Humans v is a Var. If this is correct, can somebody explain why we use $\rightarrow$ instead of $\leftrightarrow$ ? e.g. I saw this:

Brother(John, Paul) $\rightarrow$ Brother(Paul, John)

but wouldn't it be more

Brother(John, Paul) $\leftrightarrow$ Brother(Paul, John)?

Comment: Can you use $\neq$ in your system? How about "There is" , or "There exists"? Do you have the general context for the bottom part about brothers?

Comment: We are not allowed to use $\neq$, but $\exists$ and $\forall$. But any solution would help, maybe it will lead to another. The bottom part is from somewhere else, can't find it yet.

Comment: O.K, it is difficult to write in the comments, so I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one: two friends have other friends, I would suggest: $\forall a,b: E(a,b) \rightarrow  [ \exists c :E(a,c) \land E(b,c)] $ and I assume it is implied that if we use the letter $c$ , we have that $a \neq c , b \neq c$.

Comment: and what about the first question, do you think that is okay (if I add that "There is a C"-part)

Comment: Actually, yes, it seems correct using "There is".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two sentences meaning it that *for every* pair of people the specific property holds (you could also interpret them with *at least one* or *exactly one*) this would be my suggestion:

1. $\forall a,b: \neg(a=b) \land E(a,c) \rightarrow \neg E(b,c)$
2. I think your solution is ok, without any other constraint, this because the sentence doesn't specify other constraints (but still I'm not sure about the necessity of the existentialistic operator for c)

I also don't understand you comment about the notation: your $a,b,v$ MUST all be variables, then the possibility of them
to not represent necessary a human element of your domain should be managed or via the definition of the $E$ function or via
another function (like $Human(x)$). However like this it's ok if you have only humans in your domain.

The use of implication instead of equivalence (and I'm talking about the solution 2, because the implication in 1 doesn't make sense
to me) is because you are saying that the property holds given the fact that *a* and *b* are friends, otherwise you cannot say anything.
With equivalence (or double implication) you would also state that two people that have the same friend MUST also be friend with each 
other. Sentence 2 only specify the first relation, not the second one.